# java command not recogonized after BeagleBone reset

Tags: java, beagleboneblack

I installed oracle java 8 on my BeagleBone black using this link:
http://bradsmc.blogspot.fr/2014/06/installing-java-8-jdk-8-on-beaglebone.html

The problem is after BeagleBone reset the java command is not recogonised and I had to reenter the following commands to get the java version:
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/jdk1.8.0
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

Any idea why is this happenning?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: "I added the following lines to my `.bashrc` file to adjust the path and define JAVA_HOME in the environment" - did you do that? Have you double-checked that your `.bashrc` file is actually being used?

Comment: Better to set JAVA PATH in your .profile

Comment: set in .profile :) Thanks!